# SQL picking the lowest date and inserting them into a column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to do this:

[image]

I am trying to pick the lowest date in column "date" and inserting that lowest date in a new column. And it has to be by event.

I am not sure how do i go about doing this.

Thanks, 
Sam

Answer (score 2):

Use a window function:

```
select t.*, min(date) over (partition by event) as min_date
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()` :

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by event order by date) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```